# Extending the Background color on Hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have searched many questions in SO, but none of the answers fit well into my situation.

I am having a `col-md-2` where I have a navigation bar. I want to fill the background colour till the border of the `col-md-2' when hovering. I am able to change the color but it doesn't extend till the border.

I have created a  sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vini_Vasundharan/frtjwqhp/).

Just in case the fiddle doesnt work.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">dfsdf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdgfdgdfgdf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfdsfsd</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    cycdc
</div>
```

Css

```
.col-md-2{
    background-color:red;    
}
.col-md-2>ul>li>a:hover{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

**Update**

I understand that I have to add a `display:block` in the`a tag`. But when i apply the same in my code it doesnt really work. I will post the css that i am having.

```
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav{
    background-color:ghostwhite;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav >li{
    text-align: center;   
    display:block;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav>ul>li>a{
    color:#255C89;
    display:block;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav >li>a:hover{
    background-color:#255C89;
    color:white;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("View System Families", "Index", "LsystemFamilies")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add New System Family", "Create", "Lsystemfamilies")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("View all Systems", "Index", "Lsystems")</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear what is 'till the border of'. Try having the `:hover` on the `li` instead of the `a` - it might be what you are after

Comment: Is `.col-md-*` from bootstrap or just coincident?

Comment: its from bootstrap..

Comment: @IgalS.: I want the background color when hovering over to extend till the boorder of the col-md.2. Now the background color is only over the link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/frtjwqhp/1/ it is what you want?

Comment: Agree with @IgalS, it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. If you just want the background-color to extend all the way to the right edge of the red area, it could be as simple as adding `display:block;` to the `a`. Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: @IgalS.: Your idea works as well.

Comment: Sorry all for a badly framed question and thankls for all the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/frtjwqhp/1/

You simply need add `display: block` to `a` tag

**upd:**

According to your code selector is

```
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav > li > a
{
    display: block
}
```

**upd2:**

```
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav
{
    background-color:ghostwhite;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav>li
{
    text-align: center;   
    display:block;
    float: none;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav>li>a
{
    color:#255C89;
    display:block;
    float: none;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav>li>a:hover
{
    background-color:#255C89;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: I understand it works on fiddle. But unfortunately it doesnt work on my real code.

Comment: Please try display: block !important

Comment: i think this is exactly the same as I have in my question. Should I clear the cache or do something else to get these things working?

Comment: I could make it work by `deselecting the property `navbar-nav >li float :left`. How can I achieve the same in my code.

Comment: add float:none to element

Comment: OK. I got it right. I added the float property to null. Now it works. If you don't mind you could also add that to your answer. Anyway your answer is right. So it is being accepted.

Comment: Yes. For me the float went inside the `li`. I have not checked if it right to have it inside the `a`

Answer (score 1):

this will also work

```css
.col-md-2{
    background-color:red;
    
}
.col-md-2>ul>li:hover{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">dfsdf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdgfdgdfgdf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfdsfsd</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    cycdc
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display:block;` to the `a` has the added benefit of making the entire area clickable on hover and will accomplish your goal:

```
.col-md-2{
    background-color:red;
}
.col-md-2>ul>li>a{
    display:block;
}
.col-md-2>ul>li>a:hover{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please look into the updated question

Answer (score 1):

you could do this 2 ways:

#### 1st:

hover `li` instead `a`

```css
.col-md-2{
    background-color:red;
    
}
.col-md-2>ul>li:hover{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">dfsdf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdgfdgdfgdf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sdfdsfsd</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### 2nd

setting `display:block` to `a`  because by default is set do `default:inline`

```css
.col-md-2 {
  background-color: red;
}
.col-md-2>ul>li a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
a {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">dfsdf</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">sdgfdgdfgdf</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">sdfdsfsd</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

***Based on your comment, the solution is the same, check it your updated code:***

#### 1st:

hover `li` instead `a`

```css
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  /*remove margin/padding from ul default if not already */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav>ul>li>a {
  color: #255C89;
  display: block;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav>li>:hover {
  background-color: #255C89;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">dfsdf</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">sdgfdgdfgdf</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">sdfdsfsd</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### 2st:

setting `display:block` to `a`  because by default is set do `default:inline`

```css
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  /*remove margin/padding from ul default if not already */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav>ul>li>a {
  color: #255C89;
  display: block;
}
.col-md-2 .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #255C89;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">dfsdf</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">sdgfdgdfgdf</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">sdfdsfsd</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried both. It works on fiddle. But not with my code. Updated question with my code

Comment: It doesnt work as I have the same code posted in my question. I had to disable float in the `li` which is there by default set to left.